# C# Confluent.Apache.Avro - GenericRecord.Add(schema) having enum in schema

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

I want to publish a message to kafka using avro schema and has the enum types in the registered schema.

Schema:

```
var s = (RecordSchema)RecordSchema.Parse(
         @"{
              ""type"": ""record"",
              ""name"": ""xyz"",
              ""namespace"": ""abc.xyz.com"",
              ""fields"": [
                {
                  ""name"": ""firstname"",
                  ""type"": ""string""
                },
                {
                  ""name"": ""language"",
                  ""type"": {
                    ""type"": ""enum"",
                    ""name"": ""Language"",
                    ""symbols"": [
                      ""English"", ""Spanish""
                    ]
                  }
                }
          }"
     ); 

    var record = new GenericRecord(s);
    var language = (EnumSchema)EnumSchema.Parse(@"{""type"": ""enum"",""name"": ""Language"",""symbols"": [""English"", ""Spanish""]}");

record.Add("firstname", "xyz");
record.Add("language",  new GenericEnum(language, "English"));
```

But when I try to publish this message it gives me exception.

```
    await producer
                    .ProduceAsync(topicName, new Message<string, GenericRecord> { Key = "123", Value = record })
.ContinueWith(task => Console.WriteLine(
            task.IsFaulted
          ? $"error producing message: {task.Exception.Message}"
          : $"produced to: {task.Result.TopicPartitionOffset}"));
```

Exception:

```
 Confluent.Kafka.ProduceException`2: 'Local: Value serialization error'
Inner Exception:
AvroException: GenericEnum required to write against enum schema but found Avro.Generic.GenericEnum in field language
```

Comment: I suggest using `avrogen`, as discussed in that library's repo

Comment: @OneCricketeer - can you provide an example or link. the thing I am looking for how to add an enum in the GenericRecord field value so that it can serialize and post to kafka

Comment: The example is in the confluent dotnet github repo